# Authentication with Firebase Cloud Messaging CCS using Android-Smack

Tags: android, authentication, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have established a "TLS" connection with FCM CCS. I assume I have established it because the logs in my Android Studio do not complain about my keystore initialization anymore. Now, after "TLS" handshake should come "Authentication" and then connection to FCM CCS. For the connection I am trying to use Smack, which has been a nothing but a nightmare that is lasting 3 weeks already.

Here's the big question: Where and How do I create these "Authentication" steps in order to Authenticate with FCM CCS: Here are the initial steps according to the google docs on Firebase cloud messaging:
The following snippets illustrate how to perform authentication in CCS.

Client

```
<stream:stream to="gcm.googleapis.com"
version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client"
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
```

Server

```
<stream:features> 
<mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism>
<mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism>
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
</mechanisms>
</stream:features>
```

Client

```
<auth mechanism="PLAIN"
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-     sasl">MTI2MjAwMzQ3OTMzQHByb2plY3RzLmdjbS5hb
mFTeUIzcmNaTmtmbnFLZEZiOW1oekNCaVlwT1JEQTJKV1d0dw==</auth>
```

As you can see these are sub XML elements not Stanzas. By the way, there's more of these sub-XML exchanges between client and FCM CCS. How can I use Smack library to create the client part of this authentication process , and where would the server responses from FCM CCS come in. I can't expect to get these server responses on my smack connection even though i can set up an AsyncStanzaListener. But, what I believe is first to Authenticate with FCM CCS and then connect with Smack.

I know that Smack has classes for SASLMechanisms, how can I use them to start the authentication process, how do I build these sub XML documents. How? They are not stanzas.

Any advice would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Why are you implementing smack on Android? This is generally implemented on your app server.

Comment: Yes I see. So I must somehow learn how to create an app server. Where would this server reside. Inside my android code? How would the server communicate with my android code so I could log in to FCM CCS once the authentication step has been performed. I've seen Nodejs servers. I still believe that Smack can take care of this SASLAuthentication it has all these classes that are intended for it. @ArthurThompson

Comment: You could use a node.js server or any server (php, .net, java) any server that can make an HTTP request. This server will not be in your Android app. It will be hosted somewhere else like on Google Compute Engine or another equivalent. The XMPP connection will be between your app server and FCM (CCS). Think of FCM as being the relay point between your Android app and your server.

Comment: I dont need an HttpS request. Its got to be an XMPP server... Or wait, perhaps just for authentication i can get by with HTTPS.

Comment: @i_o Did u got any solution !! I also stuck in similar issue: what I trying with **XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder.setConfig(..)** & then trying to  **connect()** . But after receive callback in **public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {** I perform **XMPPTCPConnection.connect()** call. But it giving me following error and nothing happening after then. **org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.** Any suggestion !!

Comment: @HitendraJoshi Why are you trying to connect when you receive the callback. When you receive the connected callback, it means you are connected. You should try to login inside the connected callback method. But I think you might be missing an SSLsocket object. If I cant see your code, I cant help you. Post a question a direct me to it so I can see your code.

Comment: sorry for wrong written. I am not connect when call back receive. I  perform connection.login()" at that time and error occur while authentication.